# Wasn't the Gray's Sports Almanac supposed to be thicker?

Tags: back-to-the-future, back-to-the-future-ii

If there was really such a book that contained all sports results (football, baseball, races etc.) within 50 years, wouldn't it be a little bit thicker than just a magazine size?

Maybe something like this:

[image: Berkshire encyclopedia of world sport]

Comment: I can't remember but do we see the content in the almanac?  but if it's just a listing of date the fixture and result it might be possible.

Comment: saying that you would have a date and all the fixtures for it and a time

Comment: Time travel is no problem, but it breaks your suspension of disbelief that the sports almanac is too thin?